# Why is my header taller than it's supposed to be?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm taking my normal website, http://christianselig.com and converting it to a Wordpress site at http://christianselig.com/wp.

I'm having issues. My nav menu at the top is of differing height. It has pretty much identical styling, so I can't place why.

Comment: Not sure about the rest of it, but some of that height is coming from line height:1.5 in reset.css on line 78

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML and CSS is significantly different in both cases, what i found is

```
nav.main-navigation
```

has 10px padding applied to it.

Try

```
body nav.main-navigation {paddng:0 0 7px 0;}
```

This wll remove the top padding.

If this doesnt help, go through all the css and check where there is top and bottom margin or padding applied, then edit it accordingly to youre needs.

Comment: What? They both have the same amount of padding applied.

Comment: both what? go through the css, look where there is margin top or padding applied, override or change the co0de directly.

Comment: there is a few px difference between both versions, in the distance between the nav links and the top of the page, if this is what you mean nav.main-navigation find this selector and adjust the top padding, i was able to set it to 0 and the space disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Because the a tag in the li tag has display:block at one side but not at the other :)